# Не удалось разрешить первичную ссылку С# VisualStudio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

При сборке проекта получаю ошибки такого типа

> Не удалось разрешить первичную ссылку "SomeLib, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7148afe997f90519, processorArchitecture=MSIL", поскольку она косвенно зависит от сборки .NET Framework "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", имеющей более позднюю версию "4.0.0.0", чем версия "2.0.0.0" в текущей целевой платформе.

Открываю эту библиотеку в dotpeek и вижу, что у нее нет зависимостей на сборку System версии 4.0.0.0, только на версию для фреймворка 3.5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом я даже проверяю библиотеки по различным путям, на которые ссылается эта либа, и нигде нет и намека на более новые фреймворки

**UPD:** Версия целевой платформы - 3.5, как и версия библиотеки. Проблема в том, что библиотека берется из GAC, эту библиотеку я проинспектировал в dotpeek. На скриншоте видно, что библиотека не ссылается на библиотеки версии 4.0.0.0, в то время как ворнинги от msbuild говорят об обратном.

Answer (score 1):

> Имеющей более позднюю версию "4.0.0.0", чем версия "2.0.0.0" в текущей
> целевой платформе.

Скорее всего, у вас в свойствах проекта указана целевая платформа (*target framework*) `.NET 2.0`, переключите на `4.0` или выше.

- [Изменение требуемой версии .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2019#change-the-target-framework)

Comment: К сожалению если бы проблема была в этом, я бы не обращался сюда) целевая платформа стоит на версии 3.5, как и зависимая от нее библиотека, что видно по скриншоту из dotpeek. Никаких других зависимостей нет.